# Why ``gvfsd-metadata`` process is hogging 100% of a single core for a long time

Tags: gnome3, nautilus

Today `gvfsd-metadata` process was running for a whole day hogging 100% of a single core of my CPU. Is there any reason for it to do it?

Comment: If any gnome3 guru has better explanation or answer --- please post it ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK `gvfsd-metadata` is a process that collects file metadata when you use Nautilus. If your metadata store got corrupted somehow, it might get stuck on an infinite loop. So you'll have to kill that process, and remove the metadata store.

```
 pkill gvfsd-metadata 
 rm -rf .local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

Comment: I had too `pkill gvfsd`. Btw, using `htop`, I nice all cpu hungry processes to 19, so machine became much more usable; I think a script doing this with cpu hungry processes could be a good thing :)